# Unit test when a button is enabled using Karma in Angular2

Tags: unit-testing, angular, karma-jasmine, angular-cli

I have an Angular2 project setup using angular CLI. I'm trying to test a form component. It has two fields: email and password. Both are `required`. There's a login button of the type `submit`. It's enabled only after the user has provided valid inputs in both the fields.

```
<form (ngSubmit)="login()" #loginForm="ngForm">

        <md-input-container class="md-block">
            <input md-input [(ngModel)]="user.email" class="userEmail"
                name="userEmail" type="email" placeholder="Email" 
                ngControl="userEmail" 
            required>
        </md-input-container>
        <br>

        <md-input-container class="md-block">
            <input md-input [(ngModel)]="user.password" class="userPassword"
                name="userPassword" type="password" placeholder="Password" 
                ngControl="userPassword" 
            required>
        </md-input-container>
        <br>



        <!--the button is enabled only after all form fields are valid-->
        <button  color="primary" md-button 
            type="submit" class='loginButton'
        [disabled]="!loginForm.form.valid">
            Login
         </button>
```

Now, I want to test the button using karma. I went through the docs and was able to test the input, by giving a random input during testing and verifying it:

```
//imports...

describe('LoginComponent (inline template)', () => {
  let comp:    LoginComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TmLoginComponent>;
  let userEmail: HTMLInputElement;
  let userPassword: HTMLInputElement;
  let loginBtn: HTMLElement;
  let title: HTMLElement;



  beforeEach(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ LoginComponent ], // declare the test component
      imports: [ MaterialModule.forRoot(), FormsModule, 
                  RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(
                  [{path: 'login', component: LoginComponent}, ])
                ],
      providers: [{provide: UserAuthenticationService, useValue: uaServiceStub }, CookieService],

    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);

    comp = fixture.componentInstance; //LoginComponent test instance

    // query by CSS element selector
    userEmail = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.userEmail')).nativeElement;
    userPassword = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.userPassword')).nativeElement;
    loginBtn = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.loginButton')).nativeElement;


//tests

//this test is successful
  it('should check initial input', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(userEmail.value).toBe('')
  });

//this test is successful
  it('should check later input', async(() => {    
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      userEmail.value = 'someValue';
      userEmail.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));

      expect(userEmail.value).toBe('someValue');
    });

  }));

//EDITED: NEW TEST
it('should check loginBtn is disabled initially', () => {
  fixture.detectChanges();
  loginBtn =   fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.loginButton')).nativeElement;
  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    expect(loginBtn.disabled).toBe(true)
   })
 });


//this test fails. "Expected true to be false"
  it('should check loginBtn is enabled after inputs check out', async(() => {
   fixture.detectChanges();
   fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
   userEmail.value = 'raj@gmail.com';//valid
   userEmail.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));

   userPassword.value = 'asdf';//vaild
   userPassword.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
   fixture.detectChanges();
   expect(loginBtn.disabled).toBe(false)
  })
 }));

});
```

I don't see why the test fails. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you take a look at `DefaultValueAccessor` source code:

```
host: {'(input)': 'onChange($event.target.value)', '(blur)': 'onTouched()'},
```

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.4.2/modules/%40angular/forms/src/directives/default_value_accessor.ts#L36

you can notice that main your mistake is wrong event name.

**You have to use `input` event instead of `change`**

```
it('should check loginBtn is enabled after inputs check out', async(() => {
  fixture.detectChanges();
  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    userEmail.value = 'raj@gmail.com';
    userEmail.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));

    userPassword.value = 'asdf';
    userPassword.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(loginBtn.disabled).toBe(false)
  });
}));
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/A7JZCDFeGU4Hl1JV2D6X?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks, friend. It worked. Now, it also returns true when I put the email as simply `raj`, whereas it should be valid only if there is an `@` character followed by at least one other character (default conditions). What can I do to achieve that?

Comment: Thanks. So it's a bug. Anyway, really appreciate the help, and the extra effort you put in setting up the plunker. Sincere thanks.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. See, my login button is disabled initially (don't see that in the plunker). I've another unit test: 'should check loginBtn is disabled initially', which I've edited the question to include. Now, this test passes on its own, and the 'after inputs check out' test passes on its own. But when I test them both simultaneously, the latter fails. Any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: You need to call `detectChanges` again after `whenStable` https://plnkr.co/edit/vwyoQFBXWqYOid9eJCa9?p=preview

Comment: It worked! Thanks a ton. Btw, why DO I need to call `detectChanges()` both before AND after `whenStable`? It fails if either is missing. Can't understand the theory.

Comment: The first `detectChanges` is for setup controls, then we should wait until async actions within `NgForm` is executed (http://take.ms/TmB7N) but our template hasn't updated yet after these manipulations so we have to fire detectChanges to update our view with right state