# Angular 5 - Jasmine / Karma Test Case: Button Enable / Disable by input validation

Tags: angular, validation, button, jasmine, testcase

I am still new to Angular and its testing frameworks, Jasmine and Karma.

I’m stuck on testing a button to make sure that when the user enters the correct information, it is always enabled; mainly calling .toBeFalsy() too early before the form group validation control activates the button. **Now, I can’t share what my code is exactly for confidential reasons nor the full description of the problem**, but one public example I can give out is the Signup page of Trello shown [here](https://trello.com/signup).

Initially, the form is empty and the “Create New Account” button is disabled, where the user can’t click on it to create the account. When the user enters valid information into these three text fields, the button is activated to let the user send the request to Trello’s backend to register the account.

Let’s say that, for example, I am a developer at Trello who wants to test the case, where the button is enabled when the user fills in the correct information, using Jasmine and Karma with an Angular 5 component as my component for layout, functionality, and look-and-feel. The problem I’m tackling is the timing to which the state of the “Create New Account” button has been changed to enable, because essentially I am testing to make sure that upon filling out the form correctly, that button becomes activated and the .toBeFalsy() assertion passes.

My code for that test case, and the test suite that case is contained in, would be the following in create-account.component.spec.ts. (assuming that the component holding the MVC for the Trello account page is called CreateAccountComponent, and that all of the properties of the component are declared in create-account.component.ts)

```
// Import all the required components for the test.
// Some are redundant for this case, but are useful for testing the whole frontend page anyway.
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed, getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { CreateAccountComponent } from './create-account.component';
import { Validators, AbstractControl, ValidatorFn, Validator, FormsModule, FormGroup, FormControl, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpHeaders, HttpRequest, HttpResponse, HttpInterceptor, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser'

describe(‘Trello Create Account’, () => {

  // Test unit fields
  let createAccountPageComponent: CreateAccountComponent;
  let createAccountPage: ComponentFixture< CreateAccountComponent >;
  let rootElementOfComponent: any;
  let root_Debug_Element_Of_Component: any;

  // Create and set up the testing module.
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [CreateAccountComponent],
      imports: [ ReactiveFormsModule , HttpClientModule, RouterTestingModule ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  // Before each test case, initialize the suite fields as needed.
  beforeEach(() => {
    createAccountPage = TestBed.createComponent(CreateAccountComponent);
    createAccountPageComponent = createAccountPage.componentInstance;
    createAccountPage.detectChanges();
    rootElementOfComponent = createAccountPage.nativeElement;
    rootDebugElementOfComponent = createAccountPage.debugElement;
  });

  it('should have the Create New Account when the form fields are valid, () => {
    // Watch for the ngModelChange function call when the value of the password, e-mail address
    // and name change.
    spyOn(createAccountPageComponent, 'updateCreateNewAccount');

    // Simulate the user entering their full name.
    rootDebugElementOfComponent query(By.css('#fullNameField')).nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    createAccountPageComponent.createAccountPageForm.get(‘fullName').markAsTouched();
    createAccountPageComponent.accountFullName= "Anonymous Person";

    // Simulate the user entering their e-mail address.
    rootDebugElementOfComponent query(By.css('#emailAddressField')).nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    createAccountPageComponent.createAccountPageForm.get(‘emailAddress').markAsTouched();
    createAccountPageComponent accountEmailAddress = "anonymous@person.com";

    // Simulate the user entering a password.
    rootDebugElementOfComponent query(By.css('#passwordField')).nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    createAccountPageComponent.createAccountPageForm.get(‘password’).markAsTouched();
    createAccountPageComponent.accountPassword = "anonymous";


    // Update the new account button and have the screenshot track for changes.
    createAccountPageComponent.updateNewAccountButton();
    createAccountPage.detectChanges();

    // Once the changes are detected, test to see if the 'Create New Account' button is enabled.
    createAccountPage.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(rootElementOfComponent.querySelector('#createNewAccountButton').disabled).toBeFalsy();
      expect(rootDebugElementOfComponent.query(By.css('#createNewAccountButtonButton')).nativeElement.disabled).toBeFalsy();
    });
  });

});
```

However, this does not work because the two expect statements in the body of the then function call throw errors saying the disabled attribute is actually true.

I did look around to find out if there’s a way for me to work this out, including other StackOverflow questions [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41544323/unit-test-when-a-button-is-enabled-using-karma-in-angular2). But unfortunately, I don’t have any luck.

My initial guess would be that the whenStable() function and the body of the then function call are executed asynchronously, but I’m pretty sure I’m wrong on this one.

What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, I am a silly old bear.

Someone I'm working with reviewed the code and pointed out something I didn't know: **the spyOn function should *only* be used when testing function calls in isolation using mock objects**. So I commented this out, and the test case works as it's supposed to.

I think what happened was my component object, which is attached to the template, is actua